# __init__.py : TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm very new to Python. I'm trying to make a simple web server that pulls data from my `mongodb` DB.

This is my files architecture:

[image]

This is my code:

```
# Database
CONNECTION_URL = os.environ['mongoConnectionURL']
DATABASE_NAME = os.environ['mongoDatabaseName']
NEWS_COLLECTION = os.environ['mongodbNewsCollection']

app = FastAPI()

# TODO JS has next function i'm currently unaware of
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_headers=["Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"],
)

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return 'See /entries'

@app.get('/entries')
def getEntries():
    client = MongoClient(CONNECTION_URL)
    databaseMongo = client.get_database(DATABASE_NAME)
    collectionMongo = databaseMongo.get_collection(NEWS_COLLECTION)
    result = list(collectionMongo.find())
    for entry in result:
        return {
            'data': result
        }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, port=os.environ['PORT'])
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 927, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 663, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 367, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

The longer error log is:

[image]

Comment: you don't show the code for `getMessage`, but briefly, use `%s` for a string formatting or prefer f-strings or `.format()` anyways

Comment: oh, perhaps your port is a string and that message really is from `logging` (yuck)? try `port=int(os.environ['PORT'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uvicorn.run(app, port=os.environ['PORT'])
```

That line is causing the problem.  `port` needs to be an integer, but you're passing it as a string.

Convert it to an integer by wrapping the value in `int()`, like this:

```
uvicorn.run(app, port=int(os.environ['PORT']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because port is an str instead of an int - try changing the last line into:

```
uvicorn.run(app, port=int(os.environ['PORT']))
```